# How to get an info from DGV when mouse is on?

Tags: windows, string, datagridview

If I have a datagridview and I have a button and I want that the moment I press this button, I'll get string from the column **the mouse is on.**

Comment: When you press button - mouse is over the button your pressed :)

Comment: No buddy ,you didn't understood. When I press the button ,in the DGV there's a cell which is "marked". How do I get the information in this spesific cell?

Comment: Then put full description to question...

Answer (score 0):

For getting a current selected cell from datagridview("marked cell"):

```
mydatagridview.CurrentCell
```

and get a value of this cell

```
mydatagridview.CurrentCell.Value
```

For be sure: check if `CurrentCell` exists(C#)

```
if(mydatagridview.CurrentCell != null)
    String selectedValue = mydatagridview.CurrentCell.Value.Tostring();
```

[MSDN DataGridView documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Tnx! And how do I insert informaion into DGV?